# oracle11g regexp_replace for json

Tags: json, oracle, oracle11g

I have select:

```
select regexp_replace(regexp_substr('[{"date": "01_2016", "val":"100_22"},{"date": "02_2016","val": "200.10"}]'
,'"val":\s*("(\w| )*")', 1, level)
,'"val":\s*"((\w| )*)"', '\1', 1, 1) val
from dual
connect by regexp_substr('[{"date": "01_2016", "val":"100_22"},{"date": "02_2016","val": "200.10"}]', '"val":\s*("(\w| )*")', 1, level) is not null
;
```

If my value have format 100_10 it is ok. But I want 100.10 and this select not support this. How to write regexp_replace?

Comment: what is your purpose , inpu and output?

Comment: Can you identify how the results should look when executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `(\d+)_(\d+)` to match only the numeric values separated by an underscore:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
         '[{"date": "01_2016", "val":"100_22"},{"date": "02_2016","val": "200.10"}]',
         '"val":"(\d+)_(\d+)"',
         '"val":"\1.\2"'
       )
FROM   DUAL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody. I found the solution

```
 select regexp_replace(regexp_substr('[{"date": "01-2016", "val":"100.22"},{"date": "02-2016","val": "200.10"},{"date": "03-2016","val": "200.15"}]','"val":\s*("(\w|[..])*")', 1, level),'"val":\s*"((\w|[..])*)"', '\1', 1, 1) val, regexp_replace(regexp_substr('[{"date": "01-2016", "val":"100.22"},{"date": "02-2016","val": "200.10"},{"date": "03-2016","val": "200.15"}]' ,'"date":\s*("(\w|[-])*")', 1, level) ,'"date":\s*"((\w|[-])*)"', '\1', 1, 1) date_period from dual connect by regexp_substr('[{"date": "01-2016", "val":"100.22"},{"date": "02-2016","val": "200.10"},{"date": "03-2016","val": "200.15"}]', '"val":\s*("(\w|[..])*")', 1, level) is not null
```